# How to change a 5V output to Ground

Tags: ground, 5v

I have a PIC16F30 chip which is programmed to output either 5V or Ground from two of its pins. This is to control some jumpers on an old Sega Mega Drive.

It outputs the following three combinations from pins 9 and 10 respectively

1. 5V & Ground
2. Ground & 5V
3. 5V & 5V

However as well as those outputs, I need the signals to go to another part of the Sega system, however they need to be the opposite way round. If it wasn't for situation number 3 I could just swap the wires around...

1. Ground & 5V
2. 5V & Ground
3. Ground & Ground

So you can see I need a way to swap/invert those original signals.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Use some inverters? 74HC2G04, for example.

Comment: Couldn't you just use 2 more GPIOs and do the inversion in software

Comment: I have the code in the format of a .ASM file, however I don't really know how to make that kind of change to it

Comment: How exactly does it switch 5V and 5V? Schematic?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a NPN transistor inverter:[image: NPN transistor inverter]

Or a CD4049 series inverter ic.

Comment: I already have some of these Phillips Hex Schmitt Trigger Inverter 74Hc14 SN74HC14N, would that do the trick?

Comment: Yes. And some more chars.